# What to you use as a "fuser -v -n tcp" alternative on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, tcpip, bsd

The fuser command on Mac OS X is rather primitive and can't check for processes listening on a specific port. Does anybody know a good alternative? It it enough to know which process listening on that one port.

Comment: Try `sudo lsof -i -P`

Comment: I was under the impression that lsof` only works when a task actually connects to the port. Besides one would need at least a `| grep portno` as well to get a meaningful result.

Answer (score 17):

As @vcsjones said in the comments, `lsof` is the tool for this:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:80
COMMAND PID   USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Safari  804 gordon   16u  IPv4 0x05a2cec8      0t0  TCP 192.168.6.3:50542->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
httpd   874   root    3u  IPv6 0x05a2a940      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   878   _www    3u  IPv6 0x05a2a940      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Without the `-i`, it shows all open files; with just `-i` it shows network files only; if you specify something after the `-i` you can restrict by any or all of: IPv4/6, TCP/UDP, hostname or IP, and port number/service name.

Comment: Just in case it's useful for someone like me looking to blindly kill all processes using a given port: `lsof -i tcp:5000 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill` kills all processes listening on port 5000